"V5" wire on a 7-1/2 HP single phase induction motor?
I was expecting to find V1, NOT V5 - can someone tell me what V5 means?
Working on a 7-1/2 single phase, 230V, induction, centrifugal-switch-equipped Compressor Motor.  Six wires coming out of the motor: 2 unlabelled that appear to be the centrifugal switch, U1 & U2 - assuming these a power to the main winding, and V2 & V5.  Again, I was expecting V1 & V2 to designate that beginning and end of the start winding, but found V5 instead.  I can't find a consistent definition for V5.
Anyone recognize this label?
Compressor: Ingersoll Rand 2-stage model 2475 Motor: WEG (Ingersoll Rand part number: 32309437)


where are you seeing the V5?

The "V5" is on the opposite side of same capacitor that is hooked up to V2.  All the capacitors (3 start capacitors and 2 run capacitors) are wired in parallel and produce a total of 720 microfarads.  When I disconnect the centrifugal switch wire, the capacitance at these two terminals drops to 60 microfarads which appears correct because the two run capacitors are wired in parallel (along with three start capacitors).  I always thought that start should be 3x - 6x run capacitance, but I'm seeing 12X which seems odd.
